# How to put MySQL database in project folder

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using Node.JS express and MySQL. Also I have XAMPP installed. Database is in folder `C:\xampp\mysql\data\users` now, but I want It to be in `C:\...my-project\users` so I can push it to github and other people could get it with all the other files. How can I move it to another folder and continue working with it on localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) your database.

Then you can `mysqlimport` your .sql file or simply execute in a sql query.

Also, working on plaintext sql template allows you to use version control.